# Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class Error:(org.jsonschema2pojo.gradle.)

Tags: java, android

This problem occurred after i updating my android studio to 2.0 when i try to run i get this:

> Error:warning: Ignoring InnerClasses attribute for an anonymous inner class
>   Error:(org.jsonschema2pojo.gradle.GenerateJsonSchemaTask$_configureAndroid_closure4) that doesn't come with an
>   Error:associated EnclosingMethod attribute. This class was probably produced by a
>   Error:compiler that did not target the modern .class file format. The recommended
>   Error:solution is to recompile the class from source, using an up-to-date compiler
>   Error:and without specifying any "-target" type options. The consequence of ignoring
>   Error:this warning is that reflective operations on this class will incorrectly
>   Error:indicate that it is *not* an inner class.

this is my build.gradle (Modeule: app)

Can someone explain to me how to solve this.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
//apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "tazligen.com.tazligen"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txtd'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

ext {
    supportLibVersion = "23.2.1"
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "8.4.0"
    junitVersion = "4.12"
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile "junit:junit:${junitVersion}"

    // Android Support Library
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"

    // Networking libraries
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile 'org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin:0.4.16'
    compile 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.4'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'

    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    compile 'io.realm:realm-android:0.84.1'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:android-segmented:1.0.6'

    compile 'com.github.blackfizz:eazegraph:1.2.2@aar'
    compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem. Follow these steps:
1- Close Android Studio and reopen it
2 -Re build your project

This worked to me. I hope this work to you too

Comment: i am pretty sure i tried that then i tried the solution i just gave and weirdly it worked , anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Well i solved the problem myself . Well i just removed the line

```
compile 'org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin:0.4.16'
```

and it worked. Guess in android studio 2.0 this isn't required anymore. Anyways it worked for me.

Comment: I'm wondering if it's a problem with certain dependency libraries.